# MacOS X 10.6 Portable Home Directory sync fails due to FileSync agent crashing

Tags: mac-osx, mac-osx-server, synchronization

On one of our cleanly installed MacPro machines running MacOS X 10.6.6 connected to our MacOS X 10.6.6 Server, syncing data using Portable Home Directories fails. It seems to be due to the filesync agent crashing during the home sync. We get -41 and -8026 errors, which we are suspecting are indicating that there is too much data or filesync agent can't read the files. The user is the owner of the files and can read/write to all of the files.

> < Logout> 0:: [11/02/04 13:10:42.751] Error -41 copying /Volumes/RCAUsers/earlpeng/Library/Mail/Mailboxes/email from old imac./Attachments/12081/2.2. (source = NO)
>
> < Logout> 0:: [11/02/04 13:10:42.758] Error -8062 copying /Volumes/RCAUsers/earlpeng/Library/Mail/Mailboxes/email from old imac./Attachments/12081/2.2/don@finale.tv.vcf. (source = NO)
>
> < Logout> 1:: [11/02/04 13:10:42.758] -[DeepCopyContext deepCopyError:sourceError:sourceRef:]: error = -8062, wasSource = NO: return shouldContinue = NO

Comment: PHD = Pain, Horror and Dispair.

Comment: @pfo Definitely starting to feel that Apple has given up on some core technology... The only fix I found for this was to delete the ~/.FileSync and ~/Library/FileSync folders on the local machine and on the server copy. Then restart the local machine. Nice...

Answer (score 1):

err 41 is "out of memory" error (can't do much about it, aside from deleting some data).
err 8062 is access denied error.

Run the **Disk Utility** and click on the "*Repair Permissions*" button, that should fix the 8062.